# SVProgressHud Ring/Foreground Color IOS

Tags: ios, swift, svprogresshud

I now this issue posted more times but i have not fix my issue. In my case foregroundColor is not working. Ring is not appear with darkGray color even that foregroundColor not pick any color. Please View my code and help me. Thanks

```
import SVProgressHUD
//import SVProgressHud on top

SVProgressHUD.setDefaultStyle(.custom)
SVProgressHUD.setDefaultMaskType(.custom)
SVProgressHUD.setMinimumSize(CGSize(width: 60, height: 60))
SVProgressHUD.setRingThickness(3)
SVProgressHUD.setRingNoTextRadius(20)
SVProgressHUD.setBackgroundColor(UIColor.white)
SVProgressHUD.setForegroundColor(UIColor.darkGray)
SVProgressHUD.show()
```

[image: ScreenShot of my SVProgressHud]

Comment: See my updated answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just call this method only.

```
SVProgressHUD.setDefaultStyle(.custom)
SVProgressHUD.setDefaultMaskType(.custom)
SVProgressHUD.setForegroundColor(UIColor.red)           //Ring Color
SVProgressHUD.setBackgroundColor(UIColor.yellow)        //HUD Color
SVProgressHUD.setBackgroundLayerColor(UIColor.green)    //Background Color
SVProgressHUD.show()
```

getting output like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OXCiM.png)

Comment: Yes but i want red or gray color for ring. Is it possible?

Comment: i have used same code which you given. That code have change background layer color and background color but ring not appearing like i have attached Question screenshot.

Comment: SVProgressHUD.setForegroundColor(UIColor.red) not showing color and not showing ring.

Comment: Update SVProgressHUD library.

Comment: your answer is good ProgressHud is working with red or other colors but i have seen in 3D view. In original Screen or device progressHud Ring not showing.

Comment: if my answer is correct, then accept as a correct answer and give up a vote.

Comment: @PramodTapaniya How to add image on background under loader. Like small image and outside same loader is loading. How we we do this?